How to ask the user to turn on location in flutter
I'm asking users to grant permission for location, but I came to know that this permission is used to access location if location is enabled on the phone. I actually want to scan bluetooth devices and I'm using flutter blue plus package.
await Permission.location.isGranted;


So I want to check whether location is enabled, if not I want a pop up asking the user for the location in a similar manner to how we ask for bluetooth.
So I want it to be done on a flutter project.
I'm expecting a clear cut solution.
Thanks in advance.

try this snippet of code:
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/nb_utils.dart';

Future<Position> checkLocationPremission() async {
  bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // do what you want
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      toast('Please location permission');
      logger.w("get User LocationPosition()");
      await Geolocator.openAppSettings();

      throw '${language.lblLocationPermissionDenied}';
    }
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    throw "language lbl Location Permission Denied Permanently, please enable it from setting";
  }

  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).then((value) {
    return value;
  }).catchError((e) async {
    return await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition().then((value) async {
      if (value != null) {
        return value;
      } else {
        throw "lbl Enable Location";
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      toast(e.toString());
    });
  });
}


thanks mate, now I'm getting pop up when location is off, but is there any way that can we change the content of the popup?

these are native messages you can editin them by editing the native files. for ios you can override the permission msg inside the Info.plist  like <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>  <string>This app needs access to location to manage the coverage of the restaurant and when adding a new address.</string>

hey please say how to do for android too, actually I'm looking for one such solution.

As I know it is not allowed in Android due to security concerns.

Anyway, there is a workaround we normally do. You can show your custom normal alert dialog and put the content you want the user to know, before requesting the native permission.

Step 1: Install the geolocator package in pub.dev or using the following command you can install it flutter pub add geolocator
Step 2: Add the following permission request in the AndroidManifest.xml file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Step 3:Add the Logic for Requesting their current location like an alert dialogue
Step 4:Execute the Program ie.Run the main.dart
Here is an Example code to check the location
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Location Permission Example',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _statusMessage = 'Checking permission...';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkLocationPermission();
  }

  Future<void> _checkLocationPermission() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      _statusMessage = (permission == LocationPermission.always || permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse)
          ? 'Permission Granted'
          : 'Permission Denied';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Location Permission Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _isLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text(
                'Location Permission Status: $_statusMessage',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


thanks mate, but when I checked the code from my side it's having the same issue, location is not getting on.

Yeah, Mate did you try my steps and code snippet?  and do they work

Yes, I followed your steps, but it's only granting the permission but the location not getting on,  if it's off.
